# Why can't my shell start firefox?

Tags: c, linux, shell

I'm writing a small shell as an exercis to learn C. Now I can execute custom commands like `ls` and `date` but when I try to run firefox it doesn't start. Why? My session is

```
$ ./a.out 
miniShell>> ls
ls
a.out      digenv2.c~  digenv.c.orig  miniShell.c   README.md      test
digenv     digenv.c    digenv.old.c   miniShell.c~  smallshell.c
digenv2.c  digenv.c~   LICENSE        miniShell.c.orig  smallshell.c.orig
miniShell>> date
date
Tue May 12 09:38:27 CEST 2015
miniShell>> firefox
firefox
miniShell>>
```

My program is

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define BUFFER_LEN 1024
#define BUFFERSIZE 1024

pid_t foreground = -1;

int mystrcmp(char const *, char const *);

struct command
{
    char * const *argv;
};

void err_syserr(char *fmt, ...)
{
    int errnum = errno;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    if (errnum != 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "(%d: %s)\n", errnum, strerror(errnum));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int StartsWith(const char *a, const char *b)
{
   if(strncmp(a, b, strlen(b)) == 0) return 1;
   return 0;
}


/* Helper function that spawns processes */
/*static int spawn_proc(int in, int out, struct command *cmd)
{
    pid_t pid;
    if ((pid = fork()) == 0)
    {
        if (in != 0)
        {
            if (dup2(in, 0) < 0)
                err_syserr("dup2() failed on stdin for %s: ", cmd->argv[0]);
                ;
            close(in);
        }
        if (out != 1)
        {
            if (dup2(out, 1) < 0)
                err_syserr("dup2() failed on stdout for %s: ", cmd->argv[0]);
                close(out);
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "%d: executing %s\n", (int)getpid(), cmd->argv[0]);
        execvp(cmd->argv[0], cmd->argv);
          err_syserr("failed to execute %s: ", cmd->argv[0]);
    }
    else if (pid < 0)   {
         err_syserr("fork failed: "); 
    }
    return pid;
}*/

/* Helper function that forks pipes */
/*static void fork_pipes(int n, struct command *cmd)
{
    int i;
    int in = 0;
    int fd[2];
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i)
    {
        pipe(fd);
        spawn_proc(in, fd[1], cmd + i);
        close(fd[1]);
        in = fd[0];
    }
    if (dup2(in, 0) < 0)    {
           err_syserr("dup2() failed on stdin for %s: ", cmd[i].argv[0]);
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "%d: executing %s\n", (int)getpid(), cmd[i].argv[0]);
    execvp(cmd[i].argv[0], cmd[i].argv);
     err_syserr("failed to execute %s: ", cmd[i].argv[0]);
}*/


/*Remove zoombie processes*/
/*Return if background process terminated*/
/*
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html
*/
void Janitor(int status)    {

    if(status==SIGCHLD) {   /*Child process terminated, stopped, or continued*/

        int a = 1;

        while(a)    {

            pid_t pid_my1 = waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG);
            /*WNOHANG = return immediately if no child has exited*/
            /*Wait*/
            /*http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid*/

            if(0<pid_my1)   {   /*Still things to clean up*/


                if(pid_my1!=foreground) { /*Don't stop me since it's the foregound process*/

                    /*http://linux.die.net/man/3/wait*/
                    if(WIFEXITED(status))   {   /*Child process terminated*/
                        printf("%d terminated", pid_my1);
                    }
                }
            }
            else {  /*All work done, for now*/
                a = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}







int main() {
    char line[BUFFER_LEN];  
    char* argv[100];        
    char* path= "/bin/";    
    char progpath[20];      
    int argc;               
    size_t length;
    char *token;
    int i=0;
    int pid;
    char *tokenstr;
    char *search = " ";

    int isSignal = 0;
    int isBackground = 0;

    #ifdef SIGDET
        #if SIGDET == 1
            isSignal = 1;       /*Termination detected by signals*/
        #endif
    #endif


    while(1) {
    i = 0;
    int built_in_command = 0;
        printf("miniShell>> ");                    

        if(!fgets(line, BUFFER_LEN, stdin)) { 
            break;                                
        }
        length = strlen(line);
        if (line[length - 1] == '\n') {
            line[length - 1] = '\0';
        }
        if(strcmp(line, "exit")==0) {           
            break;
        }

        if(StartsWith(line, "cd")) {           

            built_in_command=1;

            printf("change directory\n");
            tokenstr = strtok(line, search);
            tokenstr = strtok(NULL, search);
            chdir(tokenstr);
        /*TODO maybe have a check whether extra argument exist, if not go to home directory*/

        }

        token = strtok(line," ");

        while(token!=NULL) {
            argv[i]=token;
            token = strtok(NULL," ");
            i++;
        }

        if(StartsWith(line, "checkEnv")) {

            built_in_command=1;
            if (0==i)   {

                char *printenv[] = { "printenv", 0};
                char *sort[] = { "sort", 0 };
                char *less[] = { "less", 0 };
                struct command cmd[] = { {printenv}, {sort}, {less} };

                fork();
            }
            else    {

                char *tmp;
                int len = 1;
                for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
                {
                    len += strlen(argv[i]) + 2;
                }
                tmp = (char *) malloc(len);
                tmp[0] = '\0';
                int pos = 0;
                for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
                {
                    pos += sprintf(tmp + pos, "%s%s", (i == 1 ? "" : "|"), argv[i]);
                }
                char *printenv[] = { "printenv", 0};
                char *grep[] = { "grep", "-E", tmp, NULL};
                char *sort[] = { "sort", 0 };
                char *less[] = { "less", 0 };
                struct command cmd[] = { {printenv}, {grep}, {sort}, {less} };
                fork();
                free(tmp);
            }
        }



        if(0==built_in_command) {   /*Not a built in command, so let execute it*/

            argv[i]=NULL;                     

            argc=i;                           
            for(i=0; i<argc; i++) {
                printf("%s\n", argv[i]);    
            }
            strcpy(progpath, path);           
            strcat(progpath, argv[0]);            

            for(i=0; i<strlen(progpath); i++) {   
                if(progpath[i]=='\n') {
                    progpath[i]='\0';
                }
            }



            isBackground = 0;

            sigset_t my_sig;

            pid_t pid_temp;


            int lastElem = (sizeof(line)/sizeof(line[0]))-1;    /*Last input argument index*/
            /*TODO check if background process*/


             /*TODO store the time forground process started*/

            int fd[2];
            if (isBackground == 1)  {   //If backgroundprocess

                pipe(fd);  /*(two new file descriptors)*/

                /*FIXME pid_temp = fork_pipes(2, .....);*/
                pid_temp = fork();
            }

            else if (isBackground == 0) {   //If foreground process

                int isSignal = 0;   /*FIXME*/
                if (1 == isSignal)  {   /*If using signaldetection*/

                    sigemptyset(&my_sig); /*empty and initialising a signal set*/
                    sigaddset(&my_sig, SIGCHLD);    /*Adds signal to a signal set (my_sig)*/
                    /*http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sigprocmask.html*/
                    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &my_sig, NULL);
                }

                /*FIXME pid_temp = fork_pipes(2, .....);*/

                pid_temp = fork();
                foreground = pid_temp;  /*Set pid for foreground process*/

            }


            if (0<pid_temp) {
                /*Parent process*/
            }

            else if (0>pid_temp)    {
                /*Error*/
            }

            else    {
                /*Child process*/

                if (1 == isBackground)  {   //Backgroundprocess

                    dup2(fd[STDIN_FILENO], STDIN_FILENO);

                    close(fd[0]);
                    close(fd[1]);

                }

                execvp(progpath,argv);
/*TODO execute command here, some is working*/
            }

            if (0 == isBackground)  {   //Foregroundprocess



                /*Write here, Emil*/
                int status = 0;
                waitpid(pid_temp, &status, 0);

                /*Foregroundprocess terminated*/
                /*TODO How long time was the total execution time*/



                int isSignal = 0;   /*FIXME*/
                if (1 == isSignal)  {   /*If using signaldetection*/

                    int a = sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &my_sig, NULL);
                    /*http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigprocmask.2.html*/

                    if (0 == a) {
                        /*Sigprocmask was successfull*/
                    }
                    else    {
                        /*Sigprocmask was not successfull, return=-1*/
                    }
                    Janitor(SIGCHLD);
                }
            }

            else if (1==isBackground)   {

                close(fd[0]);
                close(fd[1]);
            }
        }




       /* pid= fork();              

        if(pid==0) {              
            execvp(progpath,argv);
            fprintf(stderr, "Child process could not do execvp\n");

        } else {                  
            wait(NULL);
            printf("Child exited\n");
        }*/

    }
return (0);
}

int mystrcmp(char const *p, char const *q)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; q[i]; i++)
    {
        if(p[i] != q[i])
            return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int cd(char *pth) {
    char path[BUFFERSIZE];
    char cwd[BUFFERSIZE];
    char * return_value;
    int other_return;
    strcpy(path,pth);

    if(pth[0] != '/')
    {  
        return_value = getcwd(cwd,sizeof(cwd));
        strcat(cwd,"/");
        strcat(cwd,path);
        other_return = chdir(cwd);
    } else { 
        other_return = chdir(pth);
    }
    printf("Spawned foreground process: %d\n", getpid());
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is with the path. You always assume the *command* is in `/bin/` whereas `firefox` is usually in `/usr/bin/`. So your child is going to exec `/bin/firefox` and fail. Checking the return code of `execvp` would have helped finding this. On success, `execvp` family functions don't return. So if they do, you know why.